# Installing a new exterior door into a taller existing opening

Tags: doors, installation, framing

We are remodeling our 1948 home, and the previous owner was quite tall.  We are trying to replace our exterior door, and have come across a wonderful deal on a door.  Here is the issue: How can I make a 36w x 78L door fit into a 36w x 82L frame?

Comment: I would imagine this would be a lot easier than going to other direction (bigger door in a smaller opening).

Comment: Susan, a couple of photos I feel would get you a more thorough answer (ie Exactly how much work would be involved). One inside & one outside showing the existing door (especially around & above the head area of the door).

Comment: Depending on the available space above the door, the location of the door, and the ability of the worker... you could extend the gap and install a small window above the door.  This might not be an optimal solution in all situations, but it could be an option in some.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to fix a 4" high piece to the top of the frame where the door would go.

However, you would need this to match the thickness of the new door you are fitting and you'd need to weatherproof the gap between this and the new door. Assuming that the door opens inwards you could fit a piece of wood across the gap.

[image: Door options]

Paint the wood the same colour as the frame to de-emphasise it, or paint it a contrasting colour (the same as the door perhaps) to highlight it.